# copy data after comparing a specific value

Tags: plsql, procedure

I want to make a procedure with in parameters. To be more specific, 
I have tables like the folowing TABLE1

```
|COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |  COL5 | COL6|
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   2  |  10  |  1600 |  1  |
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   2  |  20  |  1200 |  4  |
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   2  |  15  |  1100 |  3  |
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   2  |  35  |  1700 |  2  |
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   3  |  10  |  1300 |  6  |
 ----------------------------------------
|600  |  140 |   3  |  15  |  1100 |  5  |
 ----------------------------------------
```

For the same COL1 and col2/col3 , check the select different values from col4
For instance for col1=600 , col2=140/col3=2 and col2=140/col3=3
Return 20 and 35

And insert in this table TABLE1 the rows
600 , 140 , 3, 20 , 1200 , 7 (seq number)
600 , 140 , 3, 35 , 1700 , 8 (seq number)

But I don't know how can I do the insert statement :(

```
    PROCEDURE COPY_COLUMNS  (    P_COL1         IN      A.COL1%TYPE,
                                     P_FROM_COL2    IN      B.COL2%TYPE,
                                     P_FROM_COL3    IN      B.COL3%TYPE,
                                     P_TO_COL2      IN      B.COL2%TYPE,
                                     P_TO_COL3      IN      B.COL3%TYPE,
                                     P_FLG1         IN      VARCHAR2,
                                     P_FLG2         IN      VARCHAR2,
                                     P_FLG3         IN      VARCHAR2,                                      
                                     P_FLG4         IN      VARCHAR2,
                                     P_FLG5         IN      VARCHAR2
                                ) IS


    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT *
                   FROM A
                  WHERE COL1 = P_COL1;

    CURSOR C2 IS SELECT *
                   FROM B
                  WHERE COL1  = P_COL1
                    AND COL2  = P_COL2
                    AND COL3  = P_COL3 ;

    BEGIN

    IF P_FLG1='N' OR P_FLG2='N' OR P_FLG3='N' OR  P_FLG4 ='N' OR P_FLG5 = 'N' THEN
        GOTO label; --do nothing
    END IF;

    IF P_FLG1 = 'Y' THEN
        select COL4
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
        MINUS
        select COL4
        FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3
-- how to do insert ?

    END IF;

    IF P_FLG2 = 'Y' THEN
        select COL4
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
        MINUS
        select COL4
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3
    END IF;
    -- ..........
    <<label>>
    END;
```

Could you help me please do it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are trying to get values from one table and trying to insert them into another table. Then, you could this way.

```
Insert into YourTable(col1,col2,coln) 
              SELECT col1,col2,coln from anotherTable;
```

**Update**

After reading your recent comment, it seems like you should use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm). Even you are not require to use cursor in this case.

```
MERGE INTO destination D
   USING (SELECT col1, col2 FROM source
   WHERE [condition check]) S
   ON (D.id = S.id)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.col3, D.col4)
     VALUES (S.col3, S.col4);
```

Comment: Not exactly

I think to use cursor 

I can use a cursor like this

<pre> <code> CURSOR CFL1 IS select COL4
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
 MINUS
 select COL4
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3) 



V_REC   CFL1%ROWTYPE;



OPEN CFL1;
FETCH CFL1 INTO V_REC;
CLOSE C1;




IF P_FLG1 = 'Y' THEN
  
    FOR REC IN CFL1 LOOP
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (P_COL1, P_TO_COL2, P_TO_COL3, V_REC.COL4, --??? --  , SEQNAME.NEXTVAL);
     END LOOP;
   
END IF; <code>

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? Could you point out, what exactly you are trying ?

Comment: User gives the source col2=140, col3=2 and the destination col2=140 col3=3.0

 I want to check values of col4 that exists on source but does not exist on destination.

Then insert the values of col4, col5 for every not common col4 on destination..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post . I did not know that merge statement exists.

Comment: @prokopis Always consider accepting answer, if they are helpful :)